# Parse is not initialized in php script when page is called via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, parse-platform

**In `php/loginManager.php` I have**

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'php/contentManager.php'; 
session_start();


use Parse\ParseClient;
ParseClient::initialize('XXXXX', 'XXXXX', 'XXXXX');
use Parse\ParseObject;
use Parse\ParseUser;
use Parse\ParseException;
use Parse\ParseQuery;
use Parse\ParseACL;
use Parse\ParseRole;

function checkLoggedIn(){
    $currentUser = ParseUser::getCurrentUser();
    if ($currentUser) {
        echo 'logged in';
    } 
    else {
        echo 'NOT logged in';
    }
}
```

---

**In `settings.php` I have**

```
include("php/loginManager.php");
checkLoggedIn();
```

---

When I load `settings.php` in my browser, I get "logged in", as expected.

I'd like to get this result via ajax. This is what I tried:

```
    var $target =$('#someElement');
    var dataString ='someVar=someValue';
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'settings.php',
      data: dataString,
      success: function(payload) {
         $target.html(payload);
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        console.log(err.Message);
      }
    });
```

Unfortunately, this produces the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /Users/DOoDSoftware/Sites/project/vendor/parse/php-sdk/src/Parse/ParseUser.php on line 333

Lines 332 - 333 of `ParseUser.php` with a var_dump added:

```
    $storage = ParseClient::getStorage();
    echo var_dump($storage); // this test echoes NULL
    $userData = $storage->get("user"); // the line that generates the error
```

I added this echo to the parse initialization function:

```
public static function initialize($app_id, $rest_key, $master_key, $enableCurlExceptions = true)
{
    echo('parse initialized'); 

     //....
}
```

The "parse initialized" gets printed when I actually visit `settings.php` but not when I make the ajax call.

Obviously, Parse is not getting initialized when I make the ajax call.

1. **Why is Parse is not initialized when I make the ajax call?**
2. **What can I do so that parse is initialized when I make the ajax call?**

---

### Update:

I got it working by moving the call to `require 'php/contentManager.php';` as shown below.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
// require 'php/contentManager.php';  removed from here
session_start();


use Parse\ParseClient;
ParseClient::initialize('XXXXX', 'XXXXX', 'XXXXX');
use Parse\ParseObject;
use Parse\ParseUser;
use Parse\ParseException;
use Parse\ParseQuery;
use Parse\ParseACL;
use Parse\ParseRole;

require 'php/contentManager.php'; // added it back down here
```

**It works now, but I'd really appreciate if someone could explain why this fixes the issue**

Comment: You're sending data to the php page, so does settings.php behave differently when you visit `settings.php?someVar=someValue`? (Or when you perform an actual POST, of course.)

Comment: @MrLister Nice suggestion, but no, visiting `settings.php?someVar=someValue` produces the expected result

Comment: did you try using ajax as GET?

Comment: @charlietfl I did just now, no dice. I was able to get it working with the ajax call too by moving the call to `require 'php/contentManager.php';` to after the call to initialize parse. See my update above. It's working now but Id love to understand what the issue actually is with the original setup.

Comment: Worked for me moving it under init as well.